# Laravel integration test throwing spurious 404 error when run as a class, individual tests work fine

Tags: laravel-5, integration-testing

I'm using the new integration testing stuff in L5.1.  I'm getting some strange errors when running a test class - mostly 404's on the pages I'm testing.  Oddly, when I filter down to an individual test the test passes fine.  When I run the whole test class or test suite that it's a part of, it fails with a 404.  The route works in the browser, and the test passes when I run by itself, so it's clearly not a valid error.

The code looks something like this:

```
class MyTest extends \TestCase
{
use WithoutMiddleware;

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->mock = m::mock('MyApp\Stuff\Repository');
    $this->validator = m::mock('Illuminate\Validation\Factory');
    $this->mockedClass = m::mock('MyApp\Stuff\Service');
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_should_get_all_thingies() {
    $this->mockedClass->shouldReceive('someMethod')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('yay');
    $this->app->instance('MyApp\Stuff\Service', $this->mockedClass);

    $this->visit('/api/v1/thingies');
   }
}
```

When I run 
    `phpunit --filter=it_should_get_all_thingies` , it works fine.
When I run 
    `phpunit --filter=MyTest`, it dies with a 404.  I can copy the relevant URL from the error message into the browser and it works fine.

The only other relevant fact that I can think of is that this on an updade from L4.2 to 5.0 to 5.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out what was triggering the error and how to work around it.  I was pulling in a secondary routes file like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {
require_once_app_path(__DIR__ . '/routes2.php');

});
```

The `require_once_app_path` triggers the issue.  Didn't happen in L4.2 or L5.0, started when we upgraded to 5.1.  Replacing that with `require` seems to sort things out.

Comment: You are the savior of my soul and I owe you my life.  I was using `require_once` to break up routes into separate files as well, and switching it to `require` fixed everything.

Comment: does this any other effect like routes being added twice ?